# Flutter User creation and Signing in

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

**Here is my code**
I am trying to run this code with no avail.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthClass {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  //create account

  Future<String> createAccount(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return "Account created";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        return 'The password provided is too weak.';
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        return 'The account already exists for that email.';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error Occured';
    }
  }

  //sign in user

  Future<String> signIn(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        return 'No user found for that email.';
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        return 'Wrong password provided for that user.';
      }
    }
  }

  // reset password

  Future<String> resetPassword({
    required String email,
  }) async {
    try {
      await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(
        email: email,
      );
      return 'Email Sent';
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error Occured';
    }
  }

  //sign out

  void signOut() {
    auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

**I need some help I am getting this error,**

The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Future signIn(...) "signIn"
Future createAccount(...) "createAccount"
is where i am getting the error

Comment: Future<String> signIn(...)    "signIn" is where i am getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try on catch` blocks work like this.

`try` executes code. If that fails, it `throw`s an `Exception`.

Now, that `Exception` can be of many types and using `on` and `catch` together we can catch a `specific` exception and get that value inside `e`.

But the `on FirebaseAuthException catch (e)`, only catches `Exception`s of type `FirebaseAuthException`.

So, in a case where your `try` block throws something else, maybe `NumberException`, then it won't be caught.

For catching all other types of `Exceptions`, you need to add another `catch` block.

Like this,

```
try {
  await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    return 'No user found for that email.';
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    return 'Wrong password provided for that user.';
  }
} catch (e) {
  return 'Unknown Error.';  // Change this to whatever you want.
}
```

Think of the `try` like an `if` block. 
Then your `on FirebaseAuthException catch (e)` would be an `if else` block. 
But you also need to handle the `else` block and that is your `catch (e)`.

Hope it makes sense.